# How can I get the name of comments' author?

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphic-associations

Here is my table structure:

```
-- users
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | John  |
| 2  | Jack  |
| 3  | Peter |
+----+-------+

-- posts
+----+---------+----------------------+-----------+
| id |  title  |         body         | author_id |
+----+---------+----------------------+-----------|
| 1  | title1  | somthing             | 2         |
| 2  | title2  | whatever             | 1         |
| 3  | title3  | anything             | 3         |
+----+---------+----------------------+-----------+

-- comments
+----+-----------------+---------+-----------+
| id |     message     | post_id | author_id |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | my message      | 3       | 2         | 
| 2  | whatever        | 1       | 3         |
+----+-----------------+---------+-----------+
```

Now I want to get *a post with all its comments*. Here is my code:

```
    $post= Posts::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('id', $request->id)->first();
    $comments = $post->comments;
```

Noted that I have this relation in the `User` model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','post_id', 'id')->orderBy('id');
}
```

---

**What's my question?** I also want to  get the name of comments' author. I mean the name of the person who has written the comment. anyway, how can I make a relation on an existing relation?

**Note:** I can do that by a raw `JOIN`. But I want to know how can I do that by Laravel relations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why you define relation with `task_id`?

in user model :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','author_id', 'id');
}
```

and in comment model :

```
/**
 * comments belongs to a user.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id', 'id');
}
```

now you can get a user with comments

```
User::where("id",$userId)->with("comments")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

if you want get post with all comments you should define relation like this for post model.

in `posts` model define a relation :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments','post_id', 'id');
}
```

and in comments model :

```
/**
 * comments belongs to a post.
 */
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts', 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

now :

```
Posts::where("id",$postId)->with("comments")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: sorry for `task_id`, it was a typo, eidted.

Comment: just one question, isn't there any other way instead of `with()` ?

Comment: I've tested your solutions. but none of them isn't the answer of my question. As I've mentioned in the question, all I want to do is getting the name of authors for comments.

Comment: $selectedPost = Post::find($postId);

$selectedPost->comments()->get();

Comment: this is your answer :) just you need do like this :

if you want know comment id 1 is for which user?

Comment::where("id",$commentId)->with("user")->first();

Answer (score 2):

You can join the two tables like this

```
DB::table('comments')
    ->join('users', function ($join) {
    $join->on('comments.author_id', '=', 'users.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins